# Is it possible to pin down given workspace to given monitor in modern DE?

Tags: desktop-environment, multi-monitor, workspaces

Till now I had single monitor and I used 6 workspaces. I added second monitor, and I have still 6 workspaces in such way, that each workspace takes 2 monitors to display.

It is not useful for me, I would like to say "workspaces 1-4 go to monitor 1, workspace 6 goes to monitor 2". As a bonus it would be nice to have "... and workspace 4 goes for both", but exclusive setup is fine for me (at least for now :-) ).

Is there desktop environment allowing such configuration?

I use KDE 3.5.10 on daily basis, it is old, and I am not surprised I didn't find any option in this regard. However I have also XFCE installed, also nothing found. I tried Enlightenment, it has a bit richer set of options, but still I didn't find any option allowing binding workspace to monitor. I didn't try it, but I have read Gnome in days of 2.x had that feature, but if was dropped in 3.x series.

Important note -- **DE** means for me something on par with XFCE, LXDE, Gnome 2, not pure window manager where you move windows using keypad.

*I have openSUSE 13.2 and there is combo question [Separate workspaces on each monitor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80774/separate-workspaces-on-each-monitor) however I am interested in DE having such feature, not manual writing config files (I am to afraid that with Yast automatic changes something will eventually crash).*